# Autofac asp.net web api constructor injection works but property injection does not

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac

I am beginner in autofac and I have to use it in new legacy project asp.net web api.

I am registering of interface and injection works fine with constructor injection.
However, the constructor is being called in numerous places directly `new()`, and I don't want to replace it everywhere.

So I thought about property injection, but cannot get it to work, the dependency is always null.
The app is split into multiple projects and multiple autofac modules. Autofac configuration as per docs: https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html

I tried to make small demo app, and I was able to get property injection working using all methods from docs: https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html

```
using Autofac;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<MyDependency>().As<IMyDependency>().SingleInstance();
        
        builder.RegisterType<MyService>().OnActivated(e => e.Instance.MyDependency1 = e.Context.Resolve<IMyDependency>());
        //builder.Register(c => new MyService { MyDependency1 = c.Resolve<IMyDependency>() });
        //builder.RegisterType<MyService>().WithProperty("MyDependency1", new MyDependency()).SingleInstance();

        var container = builder.Build();
        
        container.Resolve<MyService>();
    }
}

public class MyService
{
    public IMyDependency MyDependency1 { get; set; }
}

public class MyDependency : IMyDependency
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from MyDependency1");
    }

    public MyDependency()
    {
        Hello();
    }
}

public interface IMyDependency 
{
    public void Hello();
}
```

Unfortunately none of these works for my full project, the object is always null. I know it would be difficult to get help, but maybe someone can advice what to look for?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried reproducing this using the `WithProperty` registration you have there and the test passes - I can't reproduce it, property injection is working.

If it's not working in your full project, something else is going on. Below is the totally working test I used to verify.

```cs
public class ExampleTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void PropertyInjection()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<MyDependency>().As<IMyDependency>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<MyService>().WithProperty("MyDependency1", new MyDependency()).SingleInstance();

        var container = builder.Build();
        var svc = container.Resolve<MyService>();
        Assert.NotNull(svc.MyDependency1);
    }
}

public class MyService
{
    public IMyDependency MyDependency1 { get; set; }
}

public class MyDependency : IMyDependency
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from MyDependency1");
    }

    public MyDependency()
    {
        Hello();
    }
}

public interface IMyDependency
{
    public void Hello();
}
```

Comment: yes, all is ok with the code I posted. I did it to show I more or less know how this should be done. However NONE of these methods from my code works in full project. What you have mentioned "something else" is going on, and I thought maybe someone experienced something similar. Constructor injection works fine.

Comment: In a Stack Overflow question you need to provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing the problem. That's what I thought you provided. People can't guess at what the problem should be without the code. In creating that MINIMAL repro, you may actually figure out the problem yourself. Sorry I can't help more.